# Why doesn't the sentence break the "sequence of tenses" rule?

Tags: sequence-of-tenses

In [this video](https://youtu.be/DFQRkwYAk2U?t=544) (you don't have to watch it but just in case) the teacher provided two sentences as an example of usage of "will":

> I asked the pirate where the treasure was but he wouldn't tell me.

and

> I asked the pirate where the treasure is but he won't tell me.

The last one confuses me as I remember being taught that the subordinate clause must follow the sequence of tenses rule (like in the first example) and I cannot figure out what the exception it fits to. Why is the last example grammatically correct?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with *...but he **won't** tell me* if the pirate is ***still*** refusing to give the requested information, *and that fact is significant **at time of speaking***. Compare, for example, *I asked where his wife was and he said he **isn't** married*, which is also fine if the fact of him being unmarried is still true and relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I asked the pirate where the treasure was but he wouldn't tell me.

All that is in the past tense. He would not tell me when I asked him.

WHEREAS
I asked the pirate where the treasure is but he won't tell me.

works like this: He won't tell me where the treasure is. = a general truth

So, *you asked him in the past*, but he won't tell you where it is, as a general truth in the present.

Answer (score 2):

> I asked the pirate where the treasure was but he wouldn't tell me.

A correct sentence. The person describes two things: 1) they asked the pirate a question and 2) the pirate didn't say. Note that **asked**, **was**, and **wouldn't tell** are all past tense.

> I asked the pirate where the treasure is but he won't tell me.

Again, a correct sentence. But the meaning has changed: now the speaker is describing an *ongoing* situation. The asking is still described as an event that happened in the past (**I asked**). But the location of the treasure is described in the *present* and the pirate is described as *not answer**ing*** (**won't say**), which is the present continuous tense. The speaker would use this if the pirate is still in front of them and they are reporting about the situation to a newcomer, rather than reporting about a situation that happened in the past.

I think the rule you were taught about "sequence of tenses" may not apply as broadly as you were taught.